# Saving psycopg2 connection within flask using SimpleConnectionPool

Tags: python, flask, psycopg2, connection-pooling

How do I save a psycopg2 connection on a flask server once I execute a query? I am trying to save connection from a different python file on flask. I am using this code:-

```
from flask import current_app
cursor = connection.cursor() # Connection with Database
cursor.execute(self.query) 
connection.commit()
current_app.config['pool'].putconn(connection)
```

It gives me this error.

```
'Flask' object is not subscriptable
```

I use this in the flask init file to create a connection Pool:-

```
app.config['pool'] = psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool(
        1, 10,
        host = config["HOST"],
        database = config["DATABASE"],
        user = config["USER"],
        password = config["PASSWORD"]
    )
```

This is the get_db function. It works well.

```
from flask import current_app
def get_db(self):
    return current_app.config['pool'].getconn()
```

Comment: Did you leave out `config`?  `current_app.config['pool'].putconn(connection)`

Comment: @snakecharmerb No, i do current_app.config['pool'].putconn(connection). I have updated the question –

Comment: I don't have a flask setup to hand, but if `current_app.config['pool'].getconn()` works then I don't see how `current_app.config['pool'].putconn(connection)` can be raising that error.  Can you [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback please?

Comment: @sna Thats the exact error i get. 
"Flask' object is not subscriptable".

Comment: I made a flask app and tested this.  I get `AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'putconn'` with `current_app.putconn(connection)` but no error with  `current_app.config['pool'].putconn(connection)`.  Double check that you are actually running the correct code and make sure there are no out of date pyc files.  If you still get this error please produce a proper [mre].

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yes, there was an error with the syntax. Thank you so much. Sometimes, even the smallest bugs cause big problems.

Comment: May i know how can i share the database connection pool amongst mutliple gunicorn workers?